# Why is my jQuery wait cursor code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this jQuery in a page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
        var _begdate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
        var _enddate = $("#datepickerTo").val();
        var _unit = $("#unitName").text();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = true, unit = "un", begdate = "bd", enddate = "ed" })'
                  .replace("un", encodeURIComponent(_unit))
                  .replace("bd", encodeURIComponent(_begdate))
                  .replace("ed", encodeURIComponent(_enddate)),
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            cache: false,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },
            success: function (returneddata) {
                $("body").html(returneddata);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('hey, boo-boo!');
            }
        });

        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that I try to create a wait cursor early on in the click handler:

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
```

...and then revert back to the default at the end:

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
```

However, it doesn't work - the cursor never changes. The code does work (the ajax call completes successfully), but the cursor remains stonefaced, causing the user to wonder whether anything is happening.

What do I need to do yet to get the cursor to morph into a waiting attitude?

Comment: Does this happen if mouse moves also, or only if mouse motionless? I have tried this technique and cursor does not change for me until mousemove, so in some cases I needed to change to a .gif

Comment: You need to add `document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';` to the `success()` call back function (after setting the `body`'s html content)

Comment: @ochi: Why would that (misplacement of "pointer") also prevent the "wait" from appearing? Also, if it only reverted back in the case of success, wouldn't there be a danger of the wait cursor continuing forever in the case of an error?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon It appears, and *instantly* gets changed back. If you move the pointer into the success function, it will work, because that code is run *asynchronously*

Comment: the function is executed so fast, you likely don't notice it changing (try commenting it out at the end to see if it changes in the first place - but never reverts back)

Comment: @Xatenev: If true, that's at least weird; how to make it "stick" until told otherwise?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Like already said, move the `document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';` into the success method of the `$.ajax` call. (And probably in the error method aswell)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon It's not weird. Ajax calls are async, so the code after the `$.ajax()` function executes before the ajax call finishes. If you want the cursor to change back after the ajax call completes, move that line to the callback.

Comment: use `always()` call back to change back this setting (it executes on success and on failure)

Comment: @ochi Create the answer.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: It is a "hand" pointer the whole time, whether I move the cursor or not.

Comment: Can you try this instead? --->this.style.cursor

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: Ochi's idea worked. I still wonder, though, what will be the case when there is an error - the cursor will remain a "wait" cursor until time immemorial?

Comment: Yes, which means you'll never finish your project (because the cursor is telling you that you must wait)

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to add another callback to be executed all the time (after the response - either success or failure - is received from the ajax call) - check my answer

Comment: I've added a working jsfiddle. It should be a good example of what you want. Please note that jsfiddle has a "canned" version of AJAX, but it's good for our purposes.  :-) Please see my answer below. I've also modified how to change the cursor. HTH!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the nature of the ajax calls (i.e. being async) the code executes the first line to change the cursor

`document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';`

then executes the ajax call (note: it does not wait for the response).

and then executes the last line:

`document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';`

It all happens so fast, you probably don't notice.

At some point later, the ajax response is received and handled by either the `success` or `fail` callback handlers.

To change the cursor always after the ajax response is received (either success or failure), you need to add another callback called `always` - something along the lines of:

```
...
,
 always: function () {
       document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  });
...
```

Note, depending of the version of Jquery, this could be called a `done()` callback instead.

Check documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**UPDATE**

I updated the format to current practice and added the missing call...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnGetData").click(function() {
    //var _begdate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
    // var _enddate = $("#datepickerTo").val();
    // var _unit = $("#unitName").text();
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
        contentType: 'text/plain',
        cache: false
      })
      .done(function() {
        console.log('hey, success!');
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log('hey, boo-boo!');
      })
      .always(function() {
        console.log('hey, done!');
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnGetData">Get it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
        var _begdate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
        var _enddate = $("#datepickerTo").val();
        var _unit = $("#unitName").text();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = true, unit = "un", begdate = "bd", enddate = "ed" })'
                  .replace("un", encodeURIComponent(_unit))
                  .replace("bd", encodeURIComponent(_begdate))
                  .replace("ed", encodeURIComponent(_enddate)),
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            cache: false,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            }
    }).done(function(returneddata){
        $("body").html(returneddata);
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('hey, boo-boo!');
    }).always(function(){
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
});
```

I've also "modernized" your jquery to use done(), fail() which are the newer standards. The always() handler will (maybe obviously) always run after the AJAX call returns.

I hand typed this, so I'm hoping the brackets all line up. I'm sure you'll get the gist.

By looking at [this jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you will see that `success`, `error` are deprecated.

Edit: I've created a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/richbuff/nv91vbh0/) for you. Once you click the button, the fiddle simulates a 5 second AJAX call. One change is that I changed the style of html and body `$('html,body').css('cursor','wait');`